# Alfresco Invite mail url change

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I added the gmail smtp configuration to the alfresco share. Whenever  I created a new site. Whenever I invite someone a url is sent to the corresponding person but the url which is send is the problem. It is sending the local address which when clicked by the user in different computer will take to his localhost instead of alfresco share.

[image: the pic is shown below]

How to change this url. I am using alfresco share 4.2e,CE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the properties of Alfresco's sysAdmin subsystem in your alfresco-global.properties:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/sysadmin-subsystem-props.html

e.g.:

```
share.host=myalfresco
share.port=80
```

Comment: should I use 80 port, currently I am running tomcat in 8080 port.

Comment: set the port you're using. If you've a reverse proxy in front then use  host & port of your reverse proxy

Answer (score 2):

## Edit the file alfresco-global.properties

- In Linux

  - `/opt/alfresco-5.1/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties`
- In Windows

  - `C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco-global.properties`

## Change 127.0.0.1 for ip address or hostname (for Share context only)

```
share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http
```

## Restart service alfresco